# ng deep styles make separate for different component in Angular 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am using `**ngx bootstrap modal**` in two different component and in two different component i used ::ng-deep .modal-dialog to set width and height

```
in component one

::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
width: 200px;
height : 200px
}

in another(2nd) component 
::ng-deep .modal-dialog {
    width: 400px;
    height : 400px
    }
```

but when i move to one component to another, the  ::ng-deep values becomes same looks like constants width and height this css values of the modal not changing according to component level its like global level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add custom class as explained [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-custom-css-class). In this example `gray modal-lg` CSS class is added to existing `modal-dialog` class:

```
<div role="document" class="modal-dialog gray modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

so, try to add different classes in each component (`component1` and `component2` in my example) and rewrite your CSS:

```
::ng-deep .modal-dialog.component1 {
  width: 200px;
  height : 200px
}
```

in another(2nd) component

```
::ng-deep .modal-dialog.component2 {
  width: 400px;
  height : 400px
}
```

Note, that once component is loaded this CSS class will be available globally (because of `::ng-deep`) so the latest class with the same name will win.

Comment: is there any solution, if one component has more then one modal dialog?